# How To: Convert Text Following Title Case Rules in Bash

Tags: string, bash, awk, sed, tr

How to convert string to **title case while following rules**, not just simply capitalizing every first letter of the word?

Sample rule:

- Capitalize all words, with exception to:
- Lowercase all articles (a, the), prepositions (to, at, in, with), and coordinating conjunctions (and, but, or)
- Capitalize the first and last word in a title, regardless of part of speech

Any easy way to do this in bash? One-liners appreciated.

(And just as an additional note, this is to be used in `parcellite` actions.)

Comment: `Generally capitalize all words, and capitalize all words five letters or longer.` which one of the two conditions can be omitted ?

Comment: If you don't want this to just get closed then edit your question to clarify your requirements and post sample input and expected output and you attempt to solve this. Include titles with "words" that start with numbers, numbers as the first/last "word", words that include/are delimited by  punctuation, etc in your sample or the solution you get will only work for a subset of the simplest sunny day cases.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ cat titles.txt
purple haze
Somebody To Love
fire on the mountain
THE SONG REMAINS THE SAME
Watch the NorthWind rise
eight miles high
just dropped in
strawberry letter 23

$ cat cap.awk
BEGIN { split("a the to at in on with and but or", w)
        for (i in w) nocap[w[i]] }

function cap(word) {
    return toupper(substr(word,1,1)) tolower(substr(word,2))
}

{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
      printf "%s%s", (i==1||i==NF||!(tolower($i) in nocap)?cap($i):tolower($i)),
                     (i==NF?"\n":" ")
  }
}

$ awk -f cap.awk titles.txt
Purple Haze
Somebody to Love
Fire on the Mountain
The Song Remains the Same
Watch the Northwind Rise
Eight Miles High
Just Dropped In
Strawberry Letter 23
```

**EDIT** (as a one liner):

```
$ echo "the sun also rises" | awk 'BEGIN{split("a the to at in on with and but or",w); for(i in w)nocap[w[i]]}function cap(word){return toupper(substr(word,1,1)) tolower(substr(word,2))}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){printf "%s%s",(i==1||i==NF||!(tolower($i) in nocap)?cap($i):tolower($i)),(i==NF?"\n":" ")}}'
The Sun Also Rises
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks @jas for giving a nice answer to this one. Eventually, what I needed for `parcellite` is this **one-long-liner** in the shell: (For the love of the pipe!)

```
echo '%s' | sed 's/\<./\u&/g' | sed 's/\ The\ /\ the\ /' | sed 's/\ A\ /\ a\ /' | sed 's/\ An\ /\ an\ /' | sed 's/\ As\ /\ as\ /' | sed 's/\ At\ /\ at\ /' | sed 's/\ But\ /\ but\ /' | sed 's/\ By\ /\ by\ /' | sed 's/\ For\ /\ for\ /' | sed 's/\ In\ /\ in\ /' | sed 's/\ Of\ /\ of\ /' | sed 's/\ Off\ /\ off\ /' | sed 's/\ On\ /\ on\ /' | sed 's/\ Per\ /\ per\ /' | sed 's/\ To\ /\ to\ /' | sed 's/\ Up\ /\ up\ /' | sed 's/\ Via\ /\ via\ /' | sed 's/\ And\ /\ and\ /' | sed 's/\ Nor\ /\ nor\ /' | sed 's/\ Or\ /\ or\ /' | sed 's/\ So\ /\ so\ /' | sed 's/\ Yet\ /\ yet\ /' | parcellite
```

The `sed`s were of course generated from a loop:

```
for word in {The,A,An,As,At,But,By,For,In,Of,Off,On,Per,To,Up,Via,And,Nor,Or,So,Yet}
do
    low=`echo "$word" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
    printf "sed 's/\ $word\ /\ $low\ /' | "
done
```

Thanks for those who tried. :-)