# How do I get "awk" to modify only certain lines of a file, instead of the whole file?

Tags: awk

I would like to **reuse** [this awk code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006611/how-to-convert-text-following-title-case-rules-in-bash/35012145), to properly capitalice some cue sheet audio files. This code not only capitalice all the words, but follows some capitalization rules, as explained in the linked question.

The problem is how to modify this code to capitalize **only the "TITLE" lines**, and not the whole file. For example, with this simple cue sheet:

```
FILE "Two The Beatles Songs.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "dig A pony"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "from me to you"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 03:58:02
```

And with a simple for loop plus the awk code, for example something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
for cue_file in *.cue
do
  awk 'BEGIN{split("a the to at in on with and but or",w); for(i in w)nocap[w[i]]}function cap(word){return toupper(substr(word,1,1)) tolower(substr(word,2))}{for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){printf "%s%s",(i==1||i==NF||!(tolower($i) in nocap)?cap($i):tolower($i)),(i==NF?"\n":" ")}}' "$cue_file" > ~/temp_cue_file && mv ~/temp_cue_file "$cue_file"
done
```

The result after running the script must be:

```
FILE "Two The Beatles Songs.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "Dig a Pony"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "From Me to You"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 03:58:02
```

That is, `TITLE "Dig a Pony"` instead of `TITLE "dig A pony"`. And `TITLE "From Me to You"` instead of `TITLE "from me to you"`.

The request is:

1. As explained before, the shell script must change **only the TITLE lines** (all of them), and not the rest.
2. The shell script must run under a POSIX sh shell. In my case, FreeBSD.
3. An one line awk code would be appreciated.
4. To follow the same "capitalize rules" [as the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35006611/how-to-convert-text-following-title-case-rules-in-bash/35012145) (and that the provided awk follows). That is:

   - Capitalize all words, with exception to:
   - Lowercase all articles (a, the), prepositions (to, at, in, with), and coordinating conjunctions (and, but, or)
   - Capitalize the first and last word in a title, regardless of part of speech

How can the awk code be adapted to obtain this result?

Thanks.

---

The previous one line awk code, appears expanded in the linked answer:

```sh
BEGIN { split("a the to at in on with and but or", w)
        for (i in w) nocap[w[i]] }

function cap(word) {
    return toupper(substr(word,1,1)) tolower(substr(word,2))
}

{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
      printf "%s%s", (i==1||i==NF||!(tolower($i) in nocap)?cap($i):tolower($i)),
                     (i==NF?"\n":" ")
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you make an effort to understand the code originally posted and try to modify it for your use case?

Comment: Yes, I did, but couldn't success. I have cero experience with awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  num=split("a the to at in on with and but or",array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    smallLetters[array[i]]
  }
}
/TITLE/{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    if(tolower($i) in smallLetters){
      $i=tolower(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)
    }
    else{
      if($i~/^\"/){
        $i=substr($i,1,1) toupper(substr($i,2,1)) substr($i,3)
      }
      else{
        $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)
      }
    }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                                                         ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                                                        ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  num=split("a the to at in on with and but or",array," ")                    ##Creating array for all words needs to be of lower size.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                                                        ##Running a for loop from i=1 to tillvalue of num(length of array).
    smallLetters[array[i]]                                                    ##Creating an array named smallLetters with index of variable i here.
  }
}
/TITLE/{                                                                      ##Checking condition if a line contains string TITLE then do following.
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){                                                         ##Running a for loop from 2nd field to last field of line.
    if(tolower($i) in smallLetters){                                          ##Checking condition if lower case current field is present in array smallLetters.
      $i=tolower(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)                                 ##Changing current field to lower case for 1st letter and keeping rest same as it is.
    }
    else{                                                                     ##If current field is NOT in array then do following.
      if($i~/^\"/){                                                           ##Checking if field starts from " then do following.
        $i=substr($i,1,1) toupper(substr($i,2,1)) substr($i,3)                ##Only make 2nd letter Capital since 1st is "
      }
      else{
        $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)                               ##Else make1st character capital and keep as it is.
      }
    }
  }
}
1                                                                             ##Printing edited/non-edited lines here.
'  Input_file                                                                 ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: WOW! Seems it's working now! Please, let me test it a little more before accept it :) THANKS!