# Add an exclude array to an existing awk code

Tags: awk

Given the [awk code from this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61319386/how-do-i-get-awk-to-modify-only-certain-lines-of-a-file-instead-of-the-whole/61319746?noredirect=1#comment108482413_61319746):

```sh
awk '
BEGIN{
  num=split("a the to at in on with and but or",array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    smallLetters[array[i]]
  }
}
/TITLE/{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    if(tolower($i) in smallLetters){
      $i=tolower(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)
    }
    else{
      if($i~/^\"/){
        $i=substr($i,1,1) toupper(substr($i,2,1)) substr($i,3)
      }
      else{
        $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)
      }
    }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

This code properly capitalice the lines of a file when it matches some text, in this case `TITLE`. The idea is to use it to modify some cue sheet files and properly capitalice them following three basic rules:

- Capitalize all words, with exception to:
- Lowercase all articles (a, the), prepositions (to, at, in, with), and coordinating conjunctions (and, but, or)
- Capitalize the first and last word in a title, regardless of part of speech

Well, I would like to modify the awk code, to add a second array with a **list of words to exclude**, and **always write them as they're written in the matrix**.

This would be very useful for words like: McCartney, feat., vs., CD, USA, NYC, etc. Because, without this exclusion array, they would be changed to: Mccartney, Feat., Cd, Usa, Nyc, etc.
This exclusion should be even when these words are the first and last word of the TITLE, as explained in the related question.

For example, with an array like this: `"McCartney feat. vs. CD USA NYC"` the code must convert this:

```
FILE "Two The Beatles Songs.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "dig A pony, Feat. paul mccartney"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "From Me to You"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 03:58:02
```

Into this:

```
FILE "Two The Beatles Songs.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "Dig a Pony, feat. Paul McCartney"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "From Me to You"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 03:58:02
```

Instead of doing this:

```
FILE "Two The Beatles Songs.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "Dig a Pony, Feat. Paul Mccartney"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "From Me to You"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 03:58:02
```

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry this is not clear, please do let us know whichever words you don't want to change to small letters, kindly do add more details and let us know then.

Comment: Please do add more clear examples for words which you want to keep as it is in your file.

Comment: Sorry @RavinderSingh13, maybe now it's more clear

Comment: It's fine to provide a reference to some previous question in case anyone wants to read it for additional information but please make sure that each question you post stands alone including a [mcve] it's own concise, textual sample input, expected output, and the code you've tried so far. See [ask]. Also make sure that all relevant information is included in your question, not spread out among comments under your question.

Comment: Yeah Ed Morton, you're right. I have edited it with more references and explanations to the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** OP told there could be words like `"a"` too so handle that case adding following now.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  s1="\""
  num=split("McCartney feat. vs. CD USA NYC",array," ")
  for(k=1;k<=num;k++){
     temp=tolower(array[k])
     ignoreLetters[temp]=array[k]
  }
  num=split("a the to at in on with and but or",array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    smallLetters[array[i]]=array[i]
  }
}
/TITLE/{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    front=end=nothing=both=""
    if($i~/^"/ && $i!~/"$/){
      temp=tolower(substr($i,2))
      front=1
    }
    else if($i ~ /^".*"$/){
      temp=tolower(substr($i,2,length($i)-2))
      both=1
    }
    else if($i ~/"$/ && $i!~/^"/){
      temp=tolower(substr($i,1,length($i)-1))
      end=1
    }
    else{
      temp=tolower($i)
      nothing=1
    }
    if(temp in ignoreLetters){
      if(front){
         $i=s1 ignoreLetters[temp]
      }
      else if(end){
         $i=ignoreLetters[temp] s1
      }
      else if(both){
         $i=s1 ignoreLetters[temp] s1
      }
      else if(nothing){
         $i=ignoreLetters[temp]
      }
    }
    else if(temp in smallLetters){
      if(front){
         $i=s1 smallLetters[temp]
      }
      else if(end){
         $i=smallLetters[temp] s1
      }
      else if(nothing){
         $i=smallLetters[temp]
      }
      else if(both){
         $i=s1 smallLetters[temp] s1
      }
    }
    else{
      if($i~/^\"/){
        $i=substr($i,1,1) toupper(substr($i,2,1)) substr($i,3)
      }
      else{
        $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)
      }
    }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  s1="\""
  num=split("McCartney feat. vs. CD USA NYC",array," ")
  for(k=1;k<=num;k++){
     temp=tolower(array[k])
     ignoreLetters[temp]=array[k]
  }
  num=split("a the to at in on with and but or",array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    smallLetters[array[i]]=array[i]
  }
}
/TITLE/{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    front=end=nothing=""
    if($i~/^"/){
      temp=tolower(substr($i,2))
      front=1
    }
    else if($i ~/"$/){
      temp=tolower(substr($i,1,length($i)-1))
      end=1
    }
    else{
      temp=tolower($i)
      nothing=1
    }
    if(temp in ignoreLetters){
      if(front){
         $i=s1 ignoreLetters[temp]
      }
      else if(end){
         $i=ignoreLetters[temp] s1
      }
      else if(nothing){
         $i=ignoreLetters[temp]
      }
    }
    else if(tolower($i) in smallLetters){
      $i=tolower(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)
    }
    else{
      if($i~/^\"/){
        $i=substr($i,1,1) toupper(substr($i,2,1)) substr($i,3)
      }
      else{
        $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)
      }
    }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows:

```
FILE "Two The Beatles Songs.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
TITLE "Dig a Pony, feat. Paul McCartney"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
TITLE "From Me to You"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 03:58:02
```

***What does code take care of:***

- It takes care of making mentioned words into small letters.
- It takes care of making some letters as per their style, mentioned by OP in question.
- It takes of rest of fields which DO NOT fall in any of above category and makes their first letter as capital letter.
- Code also takes care of words starting with `"` OR ending with `"` too, it will first remove them to check if they are present into user mentioned array or not and later add them as per their position.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212121/discussion-on-answer-by-ravindersingh13-add-an-exclude-array-to-an-existing-awk).