# Modify some awk code to respect preceding spaces in modified line

Tags: awk

Given the [awk code from this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61323065/add-an-exclude-array-to-an-existing-awk-code/61324038#61324038):

```sh
awk '
BEGIN{
  s1="\""
  num=split("McCartney feat. vs. CD USA NYC",array," ")
  for(k=1;k<=num;k++){
     temp=tolower(array[k])
     ignoreLetters[temp]=array[k]
  }
  num=split("a the to at in on with and but or",array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    smallLetters[array[i]]=array[i]
  }
}
/TITLE/{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    front=end=nothing=both=""
    if($i~/^"/ && $i!~/"$/){
      temp=tolower(substr($i,2))
      front=1
    }
    else if($i ~ /^".*"$/){
      temp=tolower(substr($i,2,length($i)-2))
      both=1
    }
    else if($i ~/"$/ && $i!~/^"/){
      temp=tolower(substr($i,1,length($i)-1))
      end=1
    }
    else{
      temp=tolower($i)
      nothing=1
    }
    if(temp in ignoreLetters){
      if(front){
         $i=s1 ignoreLetters[temp]
      }
      else if(end){
         $i=ignoreLetters[temp] s1
      }
      else if(both){
         $i=s1 ignoreLetters[temp] s1
      }
      else if(nothing){
         $i=ignoreLetters[temp]
      }
    }
    else if(temp in smallLetters){
      if(front){
         $i=s1 smallLetters[temp]
      }
      else if(end){
         $i=smallLetters[temp] s1
      }
      else if(nothing){
         $i=smallLetters[temp]
      }
      else if(both){
         $i=s1 smallLetters[temp] s1
      }
    }
    else{
      if($i~/^\"/){
        $i=substr($i,1,1) toupper(substr($i,2,1)) substr($i,3)
      }
      else{
        $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)
      }
    }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

This code properly capitalice the lines that contains `TITLE` in an `Input_file`, following four basic rules:

1. Capitalize all words.
2. Lowercase a given array: `"a the to at in on with and but or"`.
3. Respect the given capitalize of a second array: `"McCartney feat. vs. CD USA NYC"`.
4. Capitalize the first and last word in a title, respecting the capitalize array of point 3.

The problem is that the awk code is cutting the spaces before the `TITLE` lines.

For example, given this `Input_file`:

```
FILE "Two The Beatles Songs.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "dig A pony, Feat. paul mccartney"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "From Me to You"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 03:58:02
```

It's doing:

```
FILE "Two The Beatles Songs.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
TITLE "Dig a Pony, feat. Paul McCartney"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
TITLE "From Me to You"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 03:58:02
```

And I need this:

```
FILE "Two The Beatles Songs.wav" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "Dig a Pony, feat. Paul McCartney"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "From Me to You"
    PERFORMER "The Beatles"
    INDEX 01 03:58:02
```

In this `Input_file`, the number of spaces preceding `TITLE` are four, but this is not always! The awk code must:

- Respect the number of spaces preceding `TITLE`.
- Also, respect any number of TABs (\t) preceding `TITLE`, usually there are TABs instead of spaces!

Thank you.

Comment: Request you to please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your question. On SO we encourage users to do so.

Comment: I have deleted my answer now; once you will add your efforts I will then undo it. Please always do add your efforts there is nothing wrong  or right in them, goal is learning for everyone here.

Comment: This is really difficult to me, I have experience with `sed`, but not with `awk`. My effort was trying to modify the `/TITLE/` part, adding `.*` before: `/.*TITLE/` . But then I realized that this part is about matching, and not about restore the number of spaces preceding `TITLE`, and didn't know how to continue... ^_^U

Comment: Sure, request you to please try to understand solution and always put your efforts in your question as we all are here to learn, thank you.

Comment: Maybe is useful for someone; this is the list I'm using to properly capitalice english song titles in the cue sheet: `"a about above across after against along among an and around as at before behind below beneath beside between beyond but by despite down during except for from in inside into like near nor of off on onto or out outside over past per since the through throughout till to toward under underneath until up upon versus via vs. with within without yet"`. Put it in the `awk` code, replacing: `"a the to at in on with and but or"`.

Comment: List was done using this sources: [capitalizemytitle](https://capitalizemytitle.com/#capitalizationrules) and [List_of_English_prepositions - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Added a `match` function to get initial/starting spaces and saving them in a variable; then again adding it before `$1` since after editing fields initial spaces will be lost so re-adding them will give us initial spaces.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  s1="\""
  num=split("McCartney feat. vs. CD USA NYC",array," ")
  for(k=1;k<=num;k++){
     temp=tolower(array[k])
     ignoreLetters[temp]=array[k]
  }
  num=split("a the to at in on with and but or",array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    smallLetters[array[i]]=array[i]
  }
}
/TITLE/{
  match($0,/^[[:space:]]+/)
  spaces=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){
    front=end=nothing=both=""
    if($i~/^"/ && $i!~/"$/){
      temp=tolower(substr($i,2))
      front=1
    }
    else if($i ~ /^".*"$/){
      temp=tolower(substr($i,2,length($i)-2))
      both=1
    }
    else if($i ~/"$/ && $i!~/^"/){
      temp=tolower(substr($i,1,length($i)-1))
      end=1
    }
    else{
      temp=tolower($i)
      nothing=1
    }
    if(temp in ignoreLetters){
      if(front){
         $i=s1 ignoreLetters[temp]
      }
      else if(end){
         $i=ignoreLetters[temp] s1
      }
      else if(both){
         $i=s1 ignoreLetters[temp] s1
      }
      else if(nothing){
         $i=ignoreLetters[temp]
      }
    }
    else if(temp in smallLetters){
      if(front){
         $i=s1 smallLetters[temp]
      }
      else if(end){
         $i=smallLetters[temp] s1
      }
      else if(nothing){
         $i=smallLetters[temp]
      }
      else if(both){
         $i=s1 smallLetters[temp] s1
      }
    }
    else{
      if($i~/^\"/){
        $i=substr($i,1,1) toupper(substr($i,2,1)) substr($i,3)
      }
      else{
        $i=toupper(substr($i,1,1)) substr($i,2)
      }
    }
  }
  $1=spaces $1
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Logical understanding of answer:***

- In `BEGIN` section mentioning all words in form of array, one array is `ignoreLetters` which will have words to ignore and don't apply making them small letters or making their 1st letter as capital letter. `smallLetters` will have words that have all those words which should be in small letters.
- Then looking for line which has `TITLE` in it.
- Firstly looking for initial spaces and saving them into a variable.
- Looping through all fields of current line then.
- Now checking 3 conditions if a field is having `"` starting of field OR ending or field or on starting AND ending both for the field.
- Then checking as per above condition which array it comes to if it comes in `ignoreLetters` then keep its value as per OP's given values. If it comes in `smallLetters` then keep values in small letters. If value of current field doesn'tcome in any of these 2 then make its first letter capital(checking `"` 3 cases as mentioned before).
- Saving new value to field value and finally adding spaces to `$1` before printing. Then printing current line.